# Change file extension of download with Python

Tags: python, download, file-extension

If I'm downloading a file with a certain extension from a certain link, but want to download the file with another extension (e.g. .doc instead of .bin), how would I go about doing this in python code?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the following way:

1. Download file in the default / original format
2. Use pypandoc in a Python script to create a new file with the desired format from the original file.
3. delete original file.

These 3 steps can all be automated from a Python script.

https://pypi.org/project/pypandoc/

Example, convert a markdown file to a rst-file (remember to correct the URL):

```
import os
import requests

import pypandoc

# Download file
# TODO: Update URL
url = 'some_url/somefile.md'
r = requests.get(url)
orig_file = '/Users/user11508332/Downloads/somefile.md'
with open(orig_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

# pypandoc file extention conversion
output = pypandoc.convert_file(orig_file, 'rst')

# TODO: Place a check here to see if the new file got created

# Clean-up: Delete original file
# TODO: Place a check here to see if the old file still exists, in that case, proceed with deletion:
# os.remove(orig_file)
```

Comment: If I just had the lines up to r = requests.get(url), where is the file supposed to be saved? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: In that line, the content of the online file is read into your local computers memory and stored into the r variable

Comment: The content of r is then saved to a file in your local filesystem, I named it orig_file and made up a likely file path you might like to use.